# Load multiple images to a wpf image control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, image, bmp

I am working on a winform project which shows images from a device. 
The problem is that I am converting code from c # winform c # wpf and I'm struggling with the code that displays the images

This is the code in winform that works fine.

```
void Ps_Sample_Apl_CS_ShowSilhouette(MemoryStream buff)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(buff);
    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    ImagePic.Image = img;
    return;
}
```

This is my code that im trying to show the images but doesnt work in wpf

```
void Ps_Sample_Apl_CS_ShowSilhouette(MemoryStream buff)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(buff);

    BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.StreamSource = buff;
    //myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(img.ToString());
    //myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
    ImagePic.Source = myBitmapImage;
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();

    return;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: myBitmapImage.EndInit();ImagePic.Source = myBitmapImage;

Comment: Add `myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` right after `myBitmapImage.BeginInit();` and switch `ImagePic.Source = myBitmapImage;` with `myBitmapImage.EndInit();`

Comment: Thanks I did it, I added the `myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` and changed the position of the `ImagePic.Source = myBitmapImage;` with `myBitmapImage.EndInit();`, but doesnt work, after `myBitmapImage.EndInit();` it backs to  `myBitmapImage.BeginInit();`

Comment: What do you mean by `it backs` ?

Comment: The execution, it back to `myBitmapImage.BeginInit();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method should look like this:

```
void Ps_Sample_Apl_CS_ShowSilhouette(MemoryStream buff)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = buff;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    ImagePic.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i said, but it seems it does not work (which surprised me too)

Comment: Thanks you two guys, I dont know why doesnt work, I used the same code  that you gaved to me. Pos me mato, lol

Comment: I found why, because im trying to update the control from another thread.